# Is it worth it to install VMWare Tools on a non-graphical Linux guest (Red Hat 7 hosting an Oracle server)

Tags: vmware-esx, rhel7, time-synchronization, vmware-tools

This came up because I was not able to activate the time synchronization function from the VCD. Most of what I've seen that discussed the benefits of installing VMWare tools looks like it applies to Windows machines, and perhaps also graphical Linux machines. I wonder if it will be worth it to install on this particular Red Hat Oracle Server, which also is mission critical to the point that my client is very apprehensive about making changes and restarting it. However, perhaps it does them a disservice by not having them installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Install VMware tools wherever possible.

This is for ease of monitoring, management and consistency. You have an option to use `open-vm-tools`. Thant would make the most sense for your setup.